# Xcode data model modification errror

Tags: ios, swift

I am following this tutorial to write my first iOS app: https://blckbirds.com/post/core-data-and-swiftui/

I tried to add my own data structure as Core Data Model and created an Entity but I realised that I had misconfigured a property (I used Boolean instead of Srting) and I wanted to change that. I did that in the CoreDataProperties.swift file but I got errors complaining about mismatching types, so I thought I will need to edit this in the .xcdatamodeld file. While I was there I thought about a new attribute I wanted to use too so I added that. Now when I try to build I get an error saying:

```
2020-04-07 17:08:07.343753+0200 sos-vac[7565:542480] [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/mani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C9F97E77-5590-482A-BDF6-C37558682D95/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C474A5D-BC6C-4350-8F2F-B83E0D1D8F9B/Library/Application%20Support/sos-vac.sqlite options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(134140) with userInfo dictionary {
    destinationModel = "(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000003a5d60>) isEditable 0, entities {\n    Patient = \"(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a40b0>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\\n    age = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eacf80>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    allergies = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead080>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    bloodType = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead180>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    name = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead200>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    other = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead100>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    sex = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead000>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n}, subentities {\\n}, userInfo {\\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\\n)\";\n}, fetch request templates {\n}";
    reason = "Can't find mapping model for migration";
    sourceModel = "(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x60000039d310>) isEditable 0, entities {\n    Patient = \"(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a8160>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\\n    age = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1700>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    allergies = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1780>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    bloodType = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1900>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    other = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1880>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    sex = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1600>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n}, subentities {\\n}, userInfo {\\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\\n)\";\n}, fetch request templates {\n}";
}
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/mani/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C9F97E77-5590-482A-BDF6-C37558682D95/data/Containers/Data/Application/0C474A5D-BC6C-4350-8F2F-B83E0D1D8F9B/Library/Application%20Support/sos-vac.sqlite options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
} ... returned error NSCocoaErrorDomain(134140) with userInfo dictionary {
    destinationModel = "(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000003a5d60>) isEditable 0, entities {\n    Patient = \"(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a40b0>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\\n    age = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eacf80>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    allergies = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead080>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    bloodType = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead180>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    name = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead200>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    other = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead100>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    sex = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead000>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n}, subentities {\\n}, userInfo {\\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\\n)\";\n}, fetch request templates {\n}";
    reason = "Can't find mapping model for migration";
    sourceModel = "(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x60000039d310>) isEditable 0, entities {\n    Patient = \"(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a8160>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\\n    age = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1700>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    allergies = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1780>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    bloodType = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1900>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    other = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1880>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n    sex = \\\"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1600>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\\\n), warnings (\\\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\\\n userInfo {\\\\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\\\";\\n}, subentities {\\n}, userInfo {\\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\\n)\";\n}, fetch request templates {\n}";
}
CoreData: annotation: <NSPersistentStoreCoordinator: 0x600003525680>: Attempting recovery from error encountered during addPersistentStore: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000003a5d60>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a40b0>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eacf80>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead080>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead180>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead200>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead100>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead000>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, sourceModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x60000039d310>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a8160>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1700>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1780>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1900>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1880>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1600>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, reason=Can't find mapping model for migration}
Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." UserInfo={destinationModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000003a5d60>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a40b0>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eacf80>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead080>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead180>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead200>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead100>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead000>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, sourceModel=(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x60000039d310>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a8160>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1700>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1780>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1900>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1880>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1600>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, reason=Can't find mapping model for migration}, ["destinationModel": (<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x6000003a5d60>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a40b0>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eacf80>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead080>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead180>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    name = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead200>), name name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier name, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead100>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000ead000>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
}, "reason": Can't find mapping model for migration, "sourceModel": (<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x60000039d310>) isEditable 0, entities {
    Patient = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x6000017a8160>) name Patient, managedObjectClassName Patient, renamingIdentifier Patient, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    age = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1700>), name age, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier age, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 100 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue 0, preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    allergies = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1780>), name allergies, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier allergies, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    bloodType = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1900>), name bloodType, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier bloodType, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    other = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1880>), name other, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier other, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n    sex = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x600000eb1600>), name sex, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Patient, renamingIdentifier sex, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null)\\n userInfo {\\n}, attributeType 800 , attributeValueClassName NSNumber, defaultValue (null), preservesValueInHistoryOnDeletion NO\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null), uniquenessConstraints (\n)";
}, fetch request templates {
 ... fetch request templates {
}]: file /Users/mani/personal-projects/sos-vac/sos-vac/AppDelegate.swift, line 61
```

Any ideas what I could do to make it work again? What other info should I add to my question? I am totally new to Swift and iOS and I am quite lost.

I tried using another iPhone simulator and then it works so I assume I should clear some cache for the iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator?

Here is the relevant part of my CoreDataProperties.swift and ContentView.swift:

````
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Patient {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Patient> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Patient>(entityName: "Patient")
    }

    @NSManaged public var bloodType: String
    @NSManaged public var allergies: String
    @NSManaged public var age: Int16
    @NSManaged public var sex: String
    @NSManaged public var other: String
    @NSManaged public var name: String

    var bloodTypeEnum: BloodType {
        set {bloodType = newValue.rawValue}
        get {BloodType(rawValue: bloodType) ?? .unknown}
    }
}

enum BloodType: String {
    case unknown = "Undefined"
    case nullNeg = "0-"
    case nullPos = "0+"
    case aNeg = "A-"
    case aPos = "A+"
    case bNeg = "B-"
    case bPos = "B+"
    case abNeg = "AB-"
    case abPos = "AB+"
}```

```import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    let bloodTypesList = ["Undefined", "0-", "0+", "A-", "A+", "B-", "B+", "AB-", "AB+"]
    let sexes = ["Undefined", "Male", "Female"]

    @State var name = ""
    @State var selectedBloodTypeIndex = 0
    @State var age = ""
    @State var allergies = ""
    @State var sexIndex = 0
    @State var other = ""

    var body: some View {
         NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Personal info")){
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)

                    Picker(selection: $selectedBloodTypeIndex, label: Text("Vércsoport")){
                        ForEach(0 ..< bloodTypesList.count) {
                                Text(self.bloodTypesList[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }

                    TextField("Age", text: $age).keyboardType(.numberPad)

                    TextField("Allergies", text: $allergies)

                    Picker(selection: $sexIndex, label: Text("Sex")){
                        ForEach(0 ..< sexes.count) {
                            Text(self.sexes[$0]).tag($0)
                        }
                    }

                    TextField("Egyéb", text: $other)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    let data = Patient(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                    data.age = Int16(self.age) ?? -1
                    data.allergies = self.allergies
                    //data.sex = self.sexes[self.sexIndex]
                    data.bloodTypeEnum = BloodType(rawValue: self.bloodTypesList[self.selectedBloodTypeIndex]) ?? .unknown
                    data.name = self.name
                    data.other = self.other

                    do {
                     try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                     print("Order saved.")
                    } catch {
                     print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }){
                    Text("Save")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        return ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
    }
}


Thanks for any help.
````

Comment: please read and consider this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. you should always copy your code here so that we can reproduce the error. we do not want to repeat your tutorial to find your error....

Comment: @Chris thanks, how can I copy the .xcdatamodeld?

Comment: you cannot copy the xcdatamodelid here...you could do push your project to github and  copy the link here if you want to (and it would be a great help for us who wanna help)

Comment: I added the relevant code that I could copy here, I don't want to make the whole codebase public at this point, do you think the info I gave already might be enough?